# Are there any applications that can detect if any programs installed use Java?

Tags: java

I have noticed that a lot of computers that run through my office have Java installed when people don't use any apps that require it. Is there any tool out there that can scan installed programs and report if they require Java?

I would like to offer to remove it for my clients, especially with all of the Java vulnerabilities out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't think there is a program that will automatically scan the exe's for you, but [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will show you if, when you run the program, if Java is called.

Also, in those situations I would probably do something like remove it and see if it brakes anything. I've done this before with older versions of quicktime that were deemed 'must have', but it would have to be a 'blind' study so to speak, as in not telling the end user, because they'll swear you broke their calc by uninstalling Java.